# modify distribution of data inside a file

Tags: bash

I need help with bash in order to modify a file.txt. I have names, each name in a line

for example

```
Peter
John
Markus
```

and I need them in the same row and with " before and at the end of each element of the vector.

```
"Peter" "John" "Markus"
```

Well, I can insert " when I have all elements in a row but I don't know how to modify the shape...all lines in a row.

```
array=( Peter John Markus )

number=${#array[@]}
for ((i=0;i<number;i++)); do
array[i]="\"${array[i]}"\"
echo "${array[i]}"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

### With awk

```
$ awk '{printf "\""$0"\" "} END{print""}' file
"Peter" "John" "Markus"
```

How it works:

- `printf "\""$0"\" "`

  With every new line of input, `$0`, this prints out a quote, the line itself, a quote and a space.
- `END{print""}`

  (optional) After we have read the last line of the file, this prints out a newline.

### With sed and tr

```
$ sed 's/.*/"&"/' file | tr '\n' ' '
"Peter" "John" "Markus"
```

How it works:

- `s/.*/"&"/`

  This puts a quote before and after every line
- `tr '\n' ' '`

  This replaces newline characters with spaces so that all names appear on the same line.

### With sed alone

```
$ sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/^/"/; s/$/"/; s/\n/" "/g' file
"Peter" "John" "Markus"
```

How it works:

- `:a;$!{N;ba}`

  This reads the whole file in to the pattern space.
- `s/^/"/`

  This adds a quote at the beginning of the file
- `s/$/"/`

  This adds a quote to the end of the file.
- `s/\n/" "/g`

  This replaces every newline with the three characters: quote-space-quote.

### With bash

To make the bash script in the question print on one line, one can use `echo -n` in place of `echo`.  In other words, replace:

```
echo "${array[i]}"
```

With:

```
echo -n "${array[i]} "
```

#### Quoting all words on one line

From the comments, suppose that our file has all the names on one line and we want to quote each individually.  Use:

```
$ cat file2
Peter John Markus
$ sed -r 's/[[:alnum:]]+/"&"/g' file2
"Peter" "John" "Markus"
```

The above is for GNU `sed`.  On OSX or other BSD system, try:

```
sed -E 's/[[:alnum:]]+/"&"/g' file2
```

Comment: Thank you for the comments in both cases. Very useful. It heps me a lot.

Comment: Your welcome.  Also, I just added a way to get your bash script to print all on one line.

Comment: another question, if I have the names Peter John Markus in a txt file in the same row and I want to put " before and after each name, how can I do it? what should I modify from sed 's/.*/"&"/' file.txt? I guess I have to change &

Comment: @EnricAgudPique Easy enough.  I just added a section to the answer for that.

Comment: Nice solution, if I wish quote punctuation characters and others, then it is better to use [:blank:], isn't it? Very useful

Comment: Yes, with a caret so that it captures all non-blanks: `sed -r 's/[^[:blank:]]+/"&"/g' file`

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -pe 'chomp; $_ = qq("$_" );chop if eof' < input
```

Explanation:

- `-p` reads the input line by line and prints what's in `$_`
- `chomp` removes a newline
- `$_ = qq("$_" )` puts a `"` before and `"<Space>` after the string.
- `chop if eof` removes the trailing space.